# rectangular markers in bubble plot (Python)

Tags: python, visualization, plotting, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to make a ['bubble'](https://python-graph-gallery.com/271-custom-your-bubble-plot/) plot, but with rectangular markers. Is it possible to do this in Python?

On x-axis should be the day of the week (Mon, Tue, Wed,...), on y-axis - counts, how many times people came to a restaurant, the area of rectangles - the number of people came to a restaurant. A height of rectangles is always the same, only a width changes.

So, one rectangle on the plot shows how many people how many times came to a restaurant on a particular day of the week. As axis y may have values > 30, bubbles are not suitable and I consider that rectangles works better.

A sketch of what I would like to draw is below.

[image]

Is it possible to draw rectangular markers or is there another good way for visualizing the same concept?

**UPDATE:**
I've already tried box and violin plots. 
The problem with boxplots is that in my case a height of a box is quite small and a tail is long. There are a lot of points indicating outliers. I would prefer to see some difference in outliers instead of a single point. With a bubble plot, it is possible to use some customized function for bubble size, e,g, logarithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine a transposed boxplot() working well... in a figure with seven subplots...

https://github.com/olisteadman/ga_pre/blob/master/archive/bar_as_rectangular_bubble.ipynb

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution, @steadfordium!

I still need to polish the plot for good visualization, but it is more about playing with design features (gaps between bars, colors etc) and I am able to do this myself.

Have a nice day!

Comment: I can’t seem to see the code from githu, can anyone post it on here? I’m trying to do a similar thing